Why is TeraTerm sending incorrect binary data over serial?
I have a VMWare Windows 10 VM set up, using a named pipe for serial data. I am then using TeraTerm to connect to that pipe.
I have a simple application that sends and receives serial data every couple of seconds. I can see the serial data being sent from the VM to the TeraTerm window.
However, when I try to send binary data as a file via TeraTerm (File -> Send file..., binary option ticked), I find that the data gets read by the application but it's slightly incorrect.
That is, I send:
FF 81 A7 13 64 00 00 90 ...
But my app reads:
FFFFFFFF FFFFFF81 FFFFFFA7 13 64 00 00 FFFFFF90 ...
I.e., there seems to be a lot of extra padding with F's.
Curiously, only the first couple of bytes are like this, the rest are fine (though the last few bytes are missing in the output).
Is this an issue on TeraTerm's side? My code is using the Poco library's serial read/write, which works fine on other apps I've written (but this is the first one I'm testing with VMs and TeraTerm).
Edit -
Here's the code that actually reads and displays the serial data:
char readBuffer[MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE_BYTES]; //2072
int lengthRead = MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE_BYTES;
if (m_pSerialPort)
{
    lengthRead = m_pSerialPort->read((char*)readBuffer, lengthRead);

    if (lengthRead > 0)
    {
        CStringA rxBytesReadableHex("RX(bytes): ");
        size_t row = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lengthRead; i++)
        {
            rxBytesReadableHex.AppendFormat("%02X ", readBuffer[i]);
            row++;
            if (row == 16)
            {
                CString rxBytesReadableHexWide(rxBytesReadableHex);
                m_listBoxRxData.AddString(rxBytesReadableHexWide);
                rxBytesReadableHex.Empty();
                rxBytesReadableHex.Append("                  ");
                row = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}


You're probably displaying them wrong, the data looks ok just incorrectly sign-extended to 32 bits

How do you receive and store the data? What data-types are you using?

Updated the post to include answers to your questions.

Use "%hhx" instead of "%x". See linked duplicate for why.

TL;DR: One part is that it's implementation defined (i.e., up to the compiler) if char is signed or unsigned. Another part is that char will very often be promoted to int, and that promotion will keep the value (so a positive value stays the same, and a negative value stays the same). Due to the need to keep the value, a sign extension is made, which for a two's complement system means that e.g. A7 turns into FFFFFFA7. The absolutely simplest solution is to change the type of readBuffer to be a std::uint8_t. Then sign extension should not happen.
